# scrollTop not working in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I am using React with basic JavaScript. *scrollTop* seems not to be working at all. I am using the code below:

```
const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)
const $container = node.getElementsByClassName('comments')
$container[0].scrollTop = 10
```

After executing this code, `scrollTop` is not working. There is already working CSS in place, with all scrolling visible for the container element.

Comment: Why are you mixing Javascript DOM handling with React. Also do you want to scroll only on a particular class element

Comment: yes I am trying to scroll on particular class element. Is there any react library for scrolling or animation that I can use ?

Answer (score 3):

I think, you should remove findDOMNode and use `ref`, when you want to get DOMElement. One of the way to solve this problem below:

```
const homeStyles = {
  overflow: 'auto',
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  border: '1px solid #333'
}

class Home extends React.Component{

  handleScrollTo = () => {
    this.container.scrollTop = 10;
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div ref={ el => this.container = el} style={homeStyles}> 
        <a onClick={this.handleScrollTo}>ScrollTo</a> <br/><br/>
        content<br/>
         content<br />
         content<br />
         content<br />
         content<br />
         content<br />
         content<br />
         content<br />
         content<br />      
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Full working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/v8z7r0pxw5

Answer (score 0):

In your method do something like this

```
componentDidMount () {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

render () {
  return (
     <div>
        <p>text here</p>
        <p>text here</p>
        <p>text here</p>
        <p>text here</p>
        <button onClick={this.onScrollToTop}>Take Me To Top</button>
     </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I do not want to use onClick, I need to use scrollTop dynamically

Comment: HI, then you can call this scrollTo function in componentDidMount liyfecycle, so as soon as component loads it scrolls to top. If you need to scroll to top anytime a component's state or props update then you should use ```componentDidUpdate``` lyfecycle in react. Hope it helps.